# DBHelper.getWirtableDatabse throws null exception

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, android-contentprovider

I am trying to code my own content provider for users. When I try to verify if the user exists,when the DBHelper tries to create the database, it throws a null exception.

Here is the content provider:

```
public class MyUserProvider extends ContentProvider {
    private UserDBHelper db;

    private static final int USERS = 10;
    private static final int USER_ID = 20;

    private static final String AUTHORITY =
            "net.ifo420.ritc.agenda.userprovider";

    private static final String BASE_PATH = "users";
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY
                                        + "/" + BASE_PATH);

    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE =
            ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE + "/users";

    public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE =
            ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE + "/user";

    private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

    static {
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH, USERS);
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH + "/#", USER_ID);
    }

    public MyUserProvider() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        db = new UserDBHelper(getContext());
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        checkColumns(projection);

        queryBuilder.setTables(UserTable.TABLE);

        int uriType = uriMatcher.match(uri);
        switch (uriType) {
            case USERS:
                break;
            case USER_ID:
                queryBuilder.appendWhere(UserTable.COLUMN_ID + " = " + uri.getLastPathSegment());
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Uknown uri " + uri);
        }
        SQLiteDatabase db1 = db.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(db1, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null, null, sortOrder);

        cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

        return cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        int uriType = uriMatcher.match(uri);
        SQLiteDatabase database = db.getReadableDatabase();
        long id = 0;
        switch (uriType) {
            case USERS:
                id = database.insert(UserTable.TABLE, null, values);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return Uri.parse(BASE_PATH + "/" + id);
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        int uriType = uriMatcher.match(uri);
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = db.getReadableDatabase();
        int rowsDeleted = 0;
        switch (uriType) {
            case USERS:
                rowsDeleted = sqLiteDatabase.delete(UserTable.TABLE, selection,
                        selectionArgs);
                break;
            case USER_ID:
                String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
                    rowsDeleted = sqLiteDatabase.delete(UserTable.TABLE,
                            UserTable.COLUMN_ID + " = " + id, null);
                } else {
                    rowsDeleted = sqLiteDatabase.delete(UserTable.TABLE,
                            UserTable.COLUMN_ID + " = " + id + " and " +
                    selection, selectionArgs);
                }
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return rowsDeleted;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
                      String[] selectionArgs) {
        int uriType = uriMatcher.match(uri);
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = db.getReadableDatabase();
        int rowsUpdated = 0;
        switch (uriType) {
            case USERS:
                rowsUpdated = sqLiteDatabase.update(UserTable.TABLE,
                        values,
                        selection,
                        selectionArgs);
                break;
            case USER_ID:
                String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
                    rowsUpdated = sqLiteDatabase.update(UserTable.TABLE,
                            values,
                            UserTable.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id,
                            null);
                } else {
                    rowsUpdated = sqLiteDatabase.update(UserTable.TABLE,
                            values,
                            UserTable.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id
                                    + " and "
                                    + selection,
                            selectionArgs);
                }
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return rowsUpdated;
    }

    private void checkColumns(String[] projection) {
        String[] available = {UserTable.COLUMN_USERNAME, UserTable.COLUMN_PASSWORD,
                            UserTable.COLUMN_ID};

        if (projection != null) {

            HashSet<String> requestedColumns =
                    new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(projection));
            HashSet<String> availableColumns =
                    new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(available));

            if (!availableColumns.containsAll(requestedColumns)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown columns in projection");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my DBHelper

```
public class UserDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "agenda.db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public UserDBHelper (Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        UserTable.onCreate(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        UserTable.onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }

Here is the sample code I am using to verify if the user exists (sorry a bit is in french):

        public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.boutonLogin:
                if (userExists()) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "L'utilisateur existe.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "L'utilisateur n'existe pas.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
    }

    private boolean userExists() {
        String username = nomUtilisateur.getText().toString();
        String password = motPasse.getText().toString();

        Cursor users = userProvider.query(MyUserProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                " WHERE username = " + nomUtilisateur.getText().toString() +
                " AND password = " + motPasse.getText().toString(), null, null);

        if (users.getCount() != 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```

Here is what the logcat gives me:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase net.info420.ritc.agendacegep.UserDBHelper.getReadableDatabase()' on a null object reference
  at net.info420.ritc.agendacegep.MyUserProvider.query(MyUserProvider.java:70)
  at net.info420.ritc.agendacegep.LoginActivity.utilisateurExiste(LoginActivity.java:69)
  at net.info420.ritc.agendacegep.LoginActivity.onClick(LoginActivity.java:57)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: Try to `return true` in `onCreate`

Comment: It still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got my own answer. Yes I couldn't instantiate my ContentProvider, but it was not only that. I changed my code and realised that I only did not really undertand the selection and selectionArgs parameters in the query.

So it went from:

```
private boolean userExists() {
    String username = nomUtilisateur.getText().toString();
    String password = motPasse.getText().toString();

    Cursor users = userProvider.query(MyUserProvider.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            " WHERE username = " + nomUtilisateur.getText().toString() +
            " AND password = " + motPasse.getText().toString(), null, null);

    if (users.getCount() != 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

To :

```
private boolean userExists() {
    String username = nomUtilisateur.getText().toString();
    String password = motPasse.getText().toString();
    String[] selection = {username, password};

    Cursor users = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query
            (Agenda.UserEntry.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            "username = ? AND password = ?", selection, null);

    if (users.getCount() != 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So, the cursor was null because I did not make a correct query and that is why my database was not created: because i did not need it at the end in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly instantiate and call a ContentProvider-  you have to go through a content resolver.  Otherwise it doesn't go through the provider's lifecycle and onCreate isn't called.

Comment: It now throws an exception when I try to get the number of results the cursor returns. It says it is null and when I try to go see the databse, it is not created.

Comment: Ok, so I've been running some tests with tags, and I noticed the onCreate method was called on the beginning of my application, not when I want to use the getWritableDatabase(). And the query() method is never called even when I call it, so it is normal the cursor is null, but the databse is still not created.

Comment: Got my answer, and part of the problem was what you mentionned. Thanks !